# Heading numbers and table of content in latex

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning

[Hi,
 I want to change Fourier Transform heading number from 1 to 2.1, Examples of Fourier Transform from 1.1 to 2.1.1, Short Time Fourier Transform from 2 to 2.2 and so on. Please help me.]

\documentclass[
    a4paper,
    oneside 
]{thesis}

[image: 97s7R].png

Comment: Try by adding `\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter.\arabic{section}} \renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}}` to your preamble.

Comment: same problem, no changes

Comment: Could you edit your post to include a minimal working example starting with a `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. The answer to your problem depends a lot of things.

Comment: I am sorry I am not getting your point. I am working on thesis and just want to manage heading numbers.  \documentclass[
 a4paper,
    oneside 
]{thesis}

Comment: @Sumair: Then try with `\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter.\arabic{section}} \renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}}}`. This should delay the changes until the very last minute. If this still doesn't have any effect, we'd need to see what `thesis.cls` looks like in order to address your concerns properly.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Unfortunately there are many different possible causes for the current appearance of the section numbers. The easiest way of finding the problem is if you can make a small test document that shows this behavior, with just one chapter, one section and one subsection.

Comment: @Werner. Thank you so much. Now it is looking as per requirements.

Comment: @Sumair: I converted my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your document class may be adjusting the way the `\section` and `\subsection` units are represented. This representation can be changed to the default hierarchical structure by adding

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter.\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}}
```

to your preamble. If there are other elements that might revert this change, it's probably better to delay the above execution to somewhere around `\begin{document}`, or automatically via

```
\AtBeginDocument{
  \renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter.\arabic{section}}
  \renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}}
}
```